# Multiple inheritance from parents with prototypes

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Is there a way in javascript to inherit prototypes of multiple classes:

ex

```
function food(){
}

food.prototype.eat = function(){}

function plant(){
}

plant.prototype.grow = function(){}


function tomato(){
} // needs to have grow and eat methods (and if possible in proto type)
```

edit:

no the tomato doesn't eat,
the eat method means to eat the food not that the food eats you

Comment: do you implement a game based on attack of killer tomatoes? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_of_the_Killer_Tomatoes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why a tomato could eat anything :)

But yes, it's possible to implement some kind of multiple inheritance in JavaScript. You just have to extend the prototype by taking the properties from both parent objects prototype:

```js
function Plant(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
Plant.prototype.grow = function() {
  document.write("<pre>" + this.name + " growing </pre>");
};

function Killer(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
Killer.prototype.eat = function() {
  document.write("<pre>" + this.name + " eating </pre>");
};

function Tomato(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

for (var key in Plant.prototype) {
  Tomato.prototype[key] = Plant.prototype[key];
}

for (var key in Killer.prototype) {
  Tomato.prototype[key] = Killer.prototype[key];
}

var killerTomato = new Tomato("yum-yum");

killerTomato.eat();
killerTomato.grow();
```

Comment: can you use a foreach method instead of a for loop?

Comment: what do you mean a foreach? for(var ... in ) is the standard way to loop over objects

Comment: like you have with arrays
[0,2,4,5].foreach(function (e){})

Comment: i found that you have the Objects.assign function

so i can do Tomato.prototype = Objects.assign(Tomato.prototype, Food.prototype) 

thanks for the solution

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be using the `Object.assign()` method.

```
function food(){
    this.value_a = 1;
}
food.prototype.eat = function(){
    console.log("eats");
}

function plant(){
    this.value_b = 2;
}

plant.prototype.grow = function(){
    console.log("grows");
}

function tomato(){
    food.call(this);
    plant.call(this);
    this.value_c = 3;
} 


Object.assign(tomato.prototype, food.prototype);
Object.assign(tomato.prototype, plant.prototype);

var new_tomato = new tomato();
console.log(new_tomato)
```

Comment: Same solution as above but other assign method, i also commented that i was going to use object.assign , still thx

Comment: yeah don't forget to call constructor for each class you're extending from.  otherwise you'll be missing all their properties they're supposed to evaluate during the initialization of the class.